# Как присвоить массиву кнопок разные методы в скрипте?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui, делегаты

у меня есть игровой проект в Unity. В нем у игрока при получении уровня выпадает 3 разные способности, которые он получает. Способности - это кнопки, добавленные в префабы и которые появляются при получении уровня. Поскольку это префабы - не могу добавить на прямую в onClick методы скрипта на объекте из инспектора.

Поэтому надо как то в скрипте добавлять методы на кнопки с помощью onClick.AddListener(метод). Поискав информацию - пришел к выводу, что нужно использовать делегаты, но как это сделать, что бы все работало? Вот пример моего не рабочего кода:

```
[SerializeField] private List<Button> _availableSkills;  //массив доступных кнопок скиллов
private delegate void FunctionsButton(); //объявление делегата. Как я понял эта штука нужна для того, что бы из методов делать переменные.

private void LoadAvailableSkills() //в методе старт присваивает функции доступным кнопкам
    {
        FunctionsButton functions;
        foreach (var skill in _availableSkills)
        {
            if (skill != null)
            {
                functions = skill.name;  //т.к. названия кнопок и методов совпадают я думал присваивать метод через название кнопки и далее...
                skill.onClick.AddListener(functions);  //здесь уже конкретной кнопке присваивать полученный метод.
                //проблема этой идеи в том, что делегат ругается, что я ему пытаюсь присвоить текст, а не метод.
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот, собственно, вопрос: как мне присвоить функции кнопкам при условии, что кнопок может быть очень много и прописывать для каждой что она делает - не вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Всем кнопкам нужно присвоить один обработчик нажатия, а уже в нём, в зависимости от имени кнопки, например (а можно использовать свойство Tag), делать обработку.

Обработчик нажатия - это метод, который вызывается для обработки события OnClick кнопки.

Писанины будет много в любом случае: или у вас будут разные обработчики, или один, но с ветвлениями. Её можно сократить, сгруппировав действия по какому-то признаку. Например, у вас написано "разные способности, которые он получает. Способности - это кнопки..." Здесь налицо одни и те же действия - добавить игроку способность. Если в Tag кнопки записать эту способность, то этой группе кнопок можно назначить один обработчик, который будет добавлять игроку способность, записанную в Tag кнопки.

Как развитие этой стратегии можно уже при добавлении кнопок использовать способность, чтобы она сама выдала нужный обработчик. То есть нужно создать класс "Способность", который будет реализовывать общие функции, а наследниками этого класса буду уже конкретные способности.

В классе "Способность" будет название способности, цена, совместимость с другими способностями и др. общие признаки, а также обработчик нажатия кнопки (общий для всех способностей, унаследованных от этого класса).

При добавлении кнопки этот класс будет выдавать свой обработчик. При нажатии на кнопку обработчик будет проверять имеющиеся средства, совместимость с имеющимися способностями, и если всё хорошо, то способность добавится игроку. Очевидно, что эти действия - общие для всех способностей, и можно использовать один обработчик.

Comment: А можете объяснить, пожалуйста, что имеется в виду под обработчиком? Если я правильно понял это какой то скрипт, который добавляется на каждую кнопку, который определяет что это за кнопка и делает необходимое действие. но в таком случае же будет так же много писанины? То есть буквально: Для этого имени - сделай то, для другого - это. Можете пояснить что вы имели в виду?